# Looking for an algorithm f(min, max, progress[from 0.0 to 1.0]) = value between min and max

Tags: algorithms

I am writing a program where I need to have a circle animation that grows from a start value to a end value and back to the starting value.

I was able to come up with a semi-solution.

```
double radiusFromProgress(double progress, double maxValue) {
  // Ensure progress is in the range [0, 1]
  progress = progress.clamp(0.0, 1.0);

  // Map progress to the range [0, pi]
  double angle = progress * pi;

  // Use the sine function to create the desired oscillation
  double output = maxValue * sin(angle);

  // Ensure output is non-negative
  output = max(0.0, output);

  return output;
}
```

I need to have the value computed to output a value between mon and max.

the form would be f(min,max,progress)
the progress values are clamped between 0.0 and 1.0 or otherwise 0% to 100%.
at 0.5 the output is max and for 0.0 and 1.0 is min.
example:

```
a = 10
b = 50
f(a, b, 0.0) =  10
f(a, b, 0.5) =  50
f(a, b, 1.0) =  10
```

Edit: well, I was certain that this would be sold using sin(angle) bot no. Found my answer over the [math community](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828368/looking-for-an-algorithm-fmin-max-v0-0-v1-0-value-between-min-and-max).

TLDR; f(a,b,c). If c is below 0.5 {a + 2 * c * (b - a)} otherwise {b - 2 * (c - 0.5) * (b - a)}